# Why is eclipse incorrectly saying my method must return a double?

Tags: java, eclipse

For a calculation I'm doing, I made a method that calculates which number is the lowest out of two:

```
public static double min(double one, double two){
    if (one < two) return one; //Return one if it is less than two
    if (two < one) return two; //Return two if it is less than one
    if (one == two) return two; //Return two, because it's the same.
}
```

However, Eclipse is telling me that I "This method must return type double".

I'm confused by this, because the method *must* be returning doubles! A number can either be greater, less than, or equal to another number. So there are no instances when it does *not* return a double.

Why is Eclipse complaining about this?

Comment: What happens when none of those three cases are met?

Comment: @peeskillet How can NONE of them be met? A number can either be less than or greater than or equal to a number!

Comment: The compiler isn't smart enough to understand your program logic

Comment: beware of `==` with doubles. Also [`Math.min`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-double-double-) is your friend.

Comment: The compiler is dumb; @peeskillet has it right. The compiler only sees "if some condition then return something". It purposely fails to see the logic. Also, your program would not return a value if one of your values were NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler has detected that if all three `if` conditions are not met, then the method would *not* return any value. This may not logically make sense in this case -- as either one of the three conditions must be met, but the compiler doesn't really care about this semantically.

Imagine that you're debugging the program, and when the method is called, `one` is greater than `two`. Then the first `if` condition is not met and the execution goes to the next condition which should be true. But if while a breakpoint is suspending the execution, you change the value of `one` to be less than `two` using the debugger, then the second `if` condition will not be met either. Eventually, this scenario leads to no condition being met.

When a `return` statement is added at the end, then no matter what scenario occurs during execution, the method is guaranteed to return a value.

Comment: But why does the compiler force me to do this? Shouldn't it be the programmer making these decisions?

Comment: @Joehot200 I added an example.

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to the answers already given, it is possible for all of these checks to fail if one of the doubles is undefined (`Double.NaN`).
This is because a comparison involving a NaN value always returns false, regardless of the other values involved.

So the compiler is correct in saying that the method needs to have a default return value. This can be shown with this test-case, which will print "defaulted":

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double one = 1;
    double two = Double.NaN;
    System.out.println(min(one, two));
}

static String min(double one, double two) {
    if (one < two) return "one";
    if (one > two) return "two";
    if (one == two) return "two";
    return "defaulted";
}
```

Comment: Neither of them can be NaN, but I can also understand that the compiler can't look THAT deeply into the code. Thank you for the extra answer.

Answer (score 2):

There must be a return statement in any execution path:

```
public static double min(double one, double two){
    if (one < two) 
        return one; 
    else if (two < one) 
        return two;
    else 
        return two; 
}
```

Even if your if statements cover all possible relations between `one` and `two`, the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: Okay, but why does it need an else? My method would always have returned a double anyway, so why is eclipse complaining?

Comment: @Joehot200 please see the last line I added

Comment: @Joehot200 You can leave out the else all together. Else here is just for clarification qnd a question of style preferences.

Answer (score 2):

For the compiler to understand this, you'll have to do it like this:

```
if (one <= two)
    return one;
else
    return two;
```

However I'd urge you to have a look at `Math.min(doube x, double y)` which does exactly what you are trying to reimplement.